# React: Load objects with a REST call and prepend new from WebSocket events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, closures

I want to implement a functionality that would load a list objects from a REST call when the page loads the first time and then it would consume new objects from WebSocket events and update/append them correspondingly.

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_REST_API}/objects`)
        .then(resp => setObjects(resp.data))
}, [])

const ws = new WebSocket(`${process.env.REACT_APP_WS_API}/objects`)
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(event.data)
    const items = [...objects]
    const index = items.findIndex((it) => it.id === obj.id)
    if (index === -1) {
        items.push(obj)
    } else {
        items[index] = obj
    }
    setObjects(items)
};
```

This code doesn't work. It opens WS connections several times. Also the initial data disappears from time to time and only the last object is shown. I understand, that it is related to the fact that react re-renders the component. And the issue with disappearing elements is most likely related to the scope of the closure used in the WS handler. At the same time, I have no idea how to solve it in React.

**Q:** How can I preload elements with a REST call and keep updating them further consuming events from WebSocket in a React component?

Answer (score 0):

- Try put ws creation into useEffect.
- UseState with arrays is different.
- If you like, use return on useEffect for closing ws when component will be unmount.

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_REST_API}/objects`)
        .then(resp => setObjects(resp.data));

const ws = new WebSocket(`${process.env.REACT_APP_WS_API}/objects`)
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(event.data)
    
    const index = objects.findIndex((it) => it.id === obj.id)
    if (index === -1) {
        setObjects((current)=>[...current, obj]);
    } else {
        items[index] = obj
setObjects((current)=> current[index]= obj);
    }
   
};    

return () => { ws.close(); }

}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't work unfortunately. Still, after the client gets an event it would clean the previous state.